# Winforms reset numeric updown value after invoke and after value changed event to 0

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, paypal, invoke

I have an value changed event on my numeric updown control in WinForms which value I change when it's needed. It's value is changed like following:

```
  private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                // after we've done all the processing, 
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                    this.lblNumberOfTransactionsFetched.Text = "Fetched:  " + numericUpDown1.Value + " out of "  + this._sortedList.Count() + " transactions";
                }));
                return;
            }
        }
```

Basically I'm showing an result on the form of an async method which does network requests towards PayPal and I'm trying to reset this value now each time when the button is pressed like this:

```
private async void materialRaisedButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   // Reset the numeric updown value to 0 again before it's displayed on the form again      
  }
```

How can  I achieve this ?

Edit: @Trey here's the actual code I'm calling when triggering the event:

```
  private async void materialRaisedButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.materialListView1.Items.Clear();
            Application.DoEvents();

            _detail = new List<TransactionDetails>();
             _sortedList = new List<Transactions>();
             var startDate = (dateFrom.Value.Year + "-" + dateFrom.Value.Date.Month + "-" + this.dateFrom.Value.Date.Day + "T00:00:00Z");
            var endDate = (dateTo.Value.Year + "-" + dateTo.Value.Date.Month + "-" + this.dateTo.Value.Date.Day + "T23:59:00Z");
            if (DateTime.Parse(startDate) > DateTime.Parse(endDate))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Start date cannot be higher than end date!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            else if (DateTime.Parse(startDate) < DateTime.Parse(endDate))
            {


                lista = new List<TransactionSearchResponseType>();
                transactions = new List<Transactions>();
                loadingCircle1.Visible = true;
                loadingCircle1.Active = true;
                lblWait.Visible = true;
                this.materialRaisedButton3.Enabled = false;
                await DoTask(startDate, endDate);
                _sortedList = transactions.DistinctBy(x => x.TransactionID).OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp).ToList();

                this.lblNumberOfTransactionsFetched.Visible = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < _sortedList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    await GetTransactionDetails(_sortedList[i].TransactionID, _sortedList[i].TimeZone);
                }

                foreach (var item in _sortedList)
                {
                    var itemInB = _detail.Where(x => x.TransactionID == item.TransactionID).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (itemInB != null)
                        item.transactionDetails.Add(itemInB);
                 }
                loadingCircle1.Active = false;
                loadingCircle1.Visible = false;
                lblWait.Visible = false;
                seedListView(_sortedList);

                listOfTransactionDetailsCSV = new List<TransactionDetails>();
                foreach (var item in _sortedList)
                {
                    listOfTransactionDetailsCSV.Add(item.transactionDetails[0]);
                }

                lblNumberOfTransactionsFetched.Visible = false;

                this.materialRaisedButton3.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: P.S> Guys, I've already tried with: setting its value upon triggering the event to 0 , but that didnt work :/ Edit: If the last changed value after the invoke was 2... For some reason it starts from that exact numeric value next time when I trigger the event...

Comment: It's winforms, so make sure your using doevents, also you may need to invalidate.  As for how to set:numericUpDown1.Value = 10;

Comment: @Trey What do you mean by "Doevents" ?

Comment: @Trey Should I trigger Application.DoEvents(); upon the button click or ?

Comment: In winforms, there is an Application.Doevents() .. it is evil, but needed.  Basically it lets your app process events such as drawing.  You stated winforms , if your not winforms, pease dis-regard.

Comment: Well doevents within an event can be problematic, but yes in this case.

Comment: @Trey Yes I'm using winforms.. I did call it upon the button click.. But on the form it shows me at first like: Fetched 2 out of 2 , Fetched 1 out of 2 , Fetched 2 out of 2 and then it displays results xD

Comment: I guess I do not understand what you are trying to do.  My apologies, could you post the actual code?  Also your invokerequired is invalid, I will get a good example

Comment: Generic example from Microsoft.....if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
 { 
  SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
  this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
 }
 else
 {
  this.textBox1.Text = text;
 }

Comment: @Trey Updated my initial question... Where would I use this piece of code, upon triggering the event to fetch the results or ?

Comment: I think I have given you enough to run with, one last tidbit before I leave:if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                // after we've done all the processing, 
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                    this.lblNumberOfTransactionsFetched.Text = "Fetched:  " + numericUpDown1.Value + " out of "  + this._sortedList.Count() + " transactions";
                }));
                return;
            }   ... in your code, what happens in invoke is NOT required...